# loading links in in-app browser in a web view in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, ios4, uiwebview

I have some local html files in resources.on launch one html,say a.html, is loaded in webview. there are some hyperlinks in that webview(or say the html content) which are links to other html files in my resources.now on click of those links I want to open them in in-app browser.

how to do this.
Any idea????

thnx!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but it might work!

Create your UIWebView and load the first html file from your bundle

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body>%@</body></html>", html] baseURL:baseURL];
webView.delegate = self;
```

Then get when the user taps a link

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        // Find which link is selected, get the file and load it into the UIWebView
    }

    return YES;
}
```